# Given two NumPy arrays, x and y of the same length, how can I select all pairs (x,y) such that x is bounded between x_min and x_max?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, x and y, of the same length. I want to select all (x[i],y[i]) such  that   x_min <x[i]<x_max. Any help?

Comment: Do you mean NumPy arrays?

Comment: Yes, i mean  NumPy arrays, thank you for your answer!

Comment: OK cool. Please remember to mark the correct answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
idx = (x_min < x) & (x < x_max)

x[idx]
y[idx]
```

and stack if necessary

```py
np.vstack((x[idx], y[idx])).T
```

Comment: How interesting @NilsWerner, so indexes in numPy can be any bool expressions ?

Comment: Yes, a mask of boolean values (same shape as array), or an array of ints (any shape)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `zip()` to iterate through corresponding pairs in same-length lists. From there, just find the min and max of your `x` list, and do a list comprehension:

```
>>> x = random.choices(range(100), k=10)  # [19, 16, 43, 89, 64, 7, 42, 9, 19, 78]
>>> y = random.choices(range(100), k=10)  # [80, 69, 37, 50, 15, 0, 56, 63, 18, 93]
>>> x_min = min(x)  # 7
>>> x_max = max(x)  # 89
>>> couples = [tup for tup in zip(x, y) if x_min < tup[0] < x_max]
>>> print(couples)
[(19, 80), (16, 69), (43, 37), (64, 15), (42, 56), (9, 63), (19, 18), (78, 93)]
```

Comment: `zip` is the best way to produce tuples indeed.